# Add 'resource' file to a C++ visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources

I am on Visual Studio 2022, and I have a project built with a C++ code.
The code looks for a data file "C:/MyData/data.dat", and the absolute path "C:/MyData/data.dat" is written in the .cpp source code.

I would like to incorporate the file data.dat into the .exe file (to make it self-contained and portable) and tell the exe file to look for data.dat 'inside itself'. How may I do this? With what should I replace "C:/MyData/data.dat" in the .cpp file.

Thank you

Comment: Add a resource file (.rc) that references the .dat file?

Comment: Is there any update?

Answer (score 1):

You have a) to add the resource in a .RC file, for example

```
FILE DATA "c:\\file.dat"
```

and b) to Load it at runtime with [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea) and [LoadResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource) and [LockResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource) and [SizeOfResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-sizeofresource).

```
auto h1 = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr),L"FILE",L"DATA");
auto h2 = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr),h1);
void* ptr = LockResource(h2);
auto sz = SizeOfResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr),h2);
// ....
// use ptr. No free needed.
```

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you wrote. What language is your comment supposed to be ? Where should I put those lines ?

Comment: You have to create a RC file and add it to the project, which includes the FILE ... line. The rest is C++ code to load the resource at run time.

Comment: This is still very unclear. Where should I put the line FILE DATA "c:\\file.dat"?

Comment: Anywhere in the RC file. I suggest you take a course at basic Win32 programming.

Comment: The code here is c++ or c using the windows api.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, I looked at this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference, and I understand better how it works. However, the website doesn't say anything on how to use the void* ptr in your example. If the file data.dat contains some numbers, e.g., "3.242354 4.4325 2.342454" in the first line, how do I access them in the C++ code from ptr ?

Comment: This is a matter of data storage. How is this number store? Ascii characters? You have to take some course on generic C++ programming and forget about windows at the moment.

Comment: sorry, does it work with absolute path? For example, it is different from a disk or folder..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the embedded file using `io`.
E.g.
Convert void* to char*

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<Libloaderapi.h>
#include"resource.h"

int main()
{
    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_FILE_DATA),  L"DATA");
    if (hResource == nullptr) {
       
        return -1;
    }
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), hResource);
    if (hGlobal == nullptr) {
       
        return -1;
    }
    void* pData = LockResource(hGlobal);
    auto sz = SizeofResource(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), hResource);
    std::cout << (char*)pData; 
}
```

resource.h

```
#define IDR_FILE_DATA       102
```

resource.rc

```
IDR_FILE_DATA                    DATA         "C://MyData//data.dat"
```

[image: enter code here]